# Redirect to auth dialogue

Tags: facebook, authentication, redirect

I have created an app. now i wanted that when the user comes to my app and only if he is not authorized then redirect it to the auth dialogue otherwise dont redirect to anywhere. i wanted to do this by the Auth referrals but in my app setting this option is not showing up, here its screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8cMV.png
if you can tell me how to enable the auth referrals option again then tell that or tell me a php code to redirect the user

Answer (score 0):

Well my friend, in facebook "developers roadmap" they are writing that they are going to remove that option.

as far as i can see this one, you need to build a self-redirect to auth dialog box if the user doesnt have access to your app.

if he does, then show something else.

hope it helps.